# how to do aggregations on csv file on two or three fields using unix script

Tags: unix

## what I have tried

```
#!/bin/sh
InputFile=$1
IFS=','
#count=0
while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4
do
        count=0
        for i in $f2
                do
                echo "$f2"
                       #count=0
                        #i=0
                        for j in $f3 ; do
                                echo "$f3"
                                count=`expr $count + 1`
                                echo "$count"
                        done
        echo " $f2 ,$f3 , $count"
        done
done < cat.csv
```

input file contains(file may be of size 1gb # this is sample file)

```
1,A,RC,1
2,B,OTC,1
3,C,RC,1
4,A,OTC,1
5,D,PB,1
6,A,RC,1
7,B,OTC,1
```

And output I want

```
A,RC,2
A,OTC,1
B,OTC,2
C,RC,1
D,PB,1
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$2 OFS $3]+=$4}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
D,PB,1
C,RC,1
A,OTC,1
A,RC,2
B,OTC,2
```

Explained:

```
BEGIN { 
    FS=OFS=","          # set delimiters
}
{
    a[$2 OFS $3]+=$4    # hash to a, $2 and $3 as key
}
END {                   # in the end
    for(i in a)         # all entries
        print i,a[i]    # output
}
```

Due to the nature of `in` operator, the output order is random. If you need it ordered, either use `sort` or GNU awk's `asort`.

Comment: can the arguments we are receiving be dynamic or it is fixed ??

Comment: Which arguments?

Comment: Number of columns present in csv file

Comment: how to write that in script and pass the dynamic  / at run time file?? like Script_name File_name that will store the output in another csv file ???

Comment: Well, that's quite a change in the requirements and deserves to be posted as a separate question. And please, gather all the requirements to the question instead of dropping them in the comments. The approach to code something like that is different from what you asked in the OP.

Comment: @Satyawan - Please read [what to do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)